# How to use elasticsearch nested aggregations in kibana visualizations

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following search in elasticsearch which returns the aggregation over a nested data structure I need, but I really want to use this as a visualization in kibana, but I can't see how this can be done:

```
GET /system_data_nested/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "consideration": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "children"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "gross": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "children.executions.consideration"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 920,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "consideration": {
      "doc_count": 486,
      "gross": {
        "value": 4492767
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ideally I could then use a horizontal bar chart to aggregate by the date histogram to bucket each time period for its consideration.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes, it is possible. I had a similar problem and solved it using a [Vega](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega-graph.html) visualization (also look at the [introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQGCipY3th8)). What it does, is sending a custom query to Elasticsearch and lets you decide which part of the response you want to visualize.

In your case it would look somewhat like this (note, this is [HJSON](https://hjson.org)):

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json
  title: Engine Score over Time
  // Define the data source
  data: {
    url: {
      index: system_data_nested
      body: {
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
          "consideration": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "children"
            },
            "aggs": {
              "gross": {
                "sum": {
                  "field": "children.executions.consideration"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    format: {
      "property": "aggregations.consideration"
    }
    mark: line
    encoding: {
      x: {
        field: key
        type: temporal
        axis: { "title": "Date" }
      }
      y: {
        field: gross.value
        type: quantitative
        axis: { "title": "Consideration" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!